# Laravel Eloquent query with joins and parameters

Tags: php, join, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a list of items (papers) and want to display all papers with a specific area.
Now i want that the user has the ability to filter the list of papers depending on different attributes.

these are the tables/models

```
Papers          
  id
  name
  author_id
  year
  paperQuality
  userRating

Authors         
  id
  name
  birthDate

Paper_areas     
  id
  paper_id
  area_id
  significance

Area            
  id
  name
  creationYear
```

I'm trying to keep Eloquent related. The user should be able to filter after papers.year, papers.paperQuality, papers.Rating, paper_areas_significance, area.creationYear

this is what i have by now

```
$paper_areas_query = Paper_areas::join('areas', function($join){
    $join->on('areas.id', '=', 'paper_areas.area_id')
    ->where('areas.creationYear', '=', 2011);
});

$paper_areas_query->join('papers', function($join){
    $join->on('papers.id', '=', 'paper_areas.paper_id')
    ->where('papers.year', '=', 2011)
    ->where('papers.paperQuality', '=', 4)
    ->where('papers.userRating', '=', 5);
});

$paper_areas_query->join('authors', function($join){
    $join->on('authors.id', '=', 'papers.author_id');
});

$paper_areas_query->select('paper_areas.id', 'paper_areas.paper_id', 'paper_areas.area_id');
$paper_areas_query->orderBy('authors.name','asc');
$paper_areas_query->orderBy('papers.title','asc');
$paper_areas_query->groupBy('papers.id');
```

Now only papers from the year 2011 are displayed, but i'm running into 2 problems

1. how can i repace the year with a parameter taken from the url?
2. how is it possible to filter the resultset in a way that i have a collection of Paper_areas? Looking into the code above it doesn't seem to be "nice" like other code.

Comment: Is the `topic_id` column in the Paper_areas table a key for your `Areas` table?

Comment: yes, sorry - i have renamed it

Answer (score 0):

I would personally modify how you're getting your data, and instead create helper functions inside the models themselves.

In your Papers model, consider something like this:

```
public function fromYear($year)
{
    return $this->where('year', '=', $year);
}

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Author');
}
```

And in your `Areas` model:

```
public function papers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Paper', 'Paper_areas', 'id', 'topic_id');
}
```

Then, with a given `Area` instance, you can get all of the authors for all of the papers in that area for a given year:

```
$id = 1;
$area = Area::find($id);
$papers = $area->papers->fromYear(2011)->get();
foreach($papers as $paper) {
    $author = $paper->author;
    // ...
}
```

As far as getting the year from a URL parameter, you can do something like this in your routes:

```
Route::get('/my-route/{year}', 'MyController@action');
```

And something like this in your controller:

```
class MyController
{
    public function action($year)
    {
        $area = /** get area instance **/;
        $papers = $area->papers->fromYear($year)->get();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, hitting the route `/my-route/2014` would pass the string 2014 into the `action` method above.  You should be able to do basically the same thing for all of your other filtering requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i should have this in mind, but the "problem" i see is that the user should be able to filter after paper_areas.significance . I see no possibility to do something like this in this query. in the variable $papers is a collection of papers. and there seems to be no possibility to get to this significance if i use belongsToMany because this attribute will not be accessible, or is it somehow?